# About salesforce SOQL relationship query

Tags: soql

How to get the parent object field from Task standard object using relationship query. select whatid,what.Email__c from Task. Its showing error. How can I get the email field from various object which is related to Task. If anyone knows help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming What is a Custom field. Following line will work. __r is usd to refer to parent object.

```
select whatid ,what__r.Email__c from Task
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution :

```
select whatid ,what__r.Email__c from Task
```

is wrong.

Try this : `Select TYPEOF What When Case Then Email__c END from Task`
See polymorphic relationships : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: how to do it with polymorphic relationships when TYPEOF is turned off